# How can I change the package name of the app in the store?

Tags: android, package

I've a big issue with the package name in the play store.
I already know it's a kind of ID through which the app is updated, searched and so on.
For these reasons it can't be changed.

The company which owns the app I'm developing 
 is going to be sold to another one: unfortunately the name of the package is obviously linked to the name of the seller (it's their website's name), therefore the buyer wants to change it. They know that almost anyone sees it, but it's there, anyway.

What can I do?

Comment: what do you mean `almost everyone sees it`, no they most certainly do not see your package name

Comment: @tyczj, of course they can: above all because it's the ID content in the URL of app page in the store; and it's not good.

Comment: no normal/non-dev person is going to know what the package name is in the url or even know it exists in there.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the package name.

Answer (score 1):

You could just remove the current application and upload a new one.

Anyway, if you need to keep the app history (i.e. download and ratings), you should directly contact Google Play support to explain the issue.

Comment: Sure, as long as you're the owner of the account, you can manage your applications as you want. Actually, I guess you should be able to upload the app with the new package name even before deleting the original one. As far as I know, the only restriction is regarding duplicate package names.

Comment: Bear in mind that removing the current application loses all of your current users, who would have to go obtain the replacement app. How much of an issue this is depends upon the number of users.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I'm guessing shouldn't be a big issue if the app is currently under development.